# Robot Framework running a Keyword within a keyword

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, keyword

Im trying to get a keyword to run other keywords without having to call it so much.

```
keyword_rp   {variable}    keyword_2  ${arg1}  ${arg2}  ${arg3}
keyword_rp   {variable}    ${return_data}=   keyword_3
keyword_rp   {variable}    keyword_4  {arg11}
etc.....
```

you can see how this clutters your robot tests
instead I want another key word that you call that takes in the entire test as arguments. Then calls the keyword_rp via python for each line.

```
keyword_rp_once   {variable}    
...               keyword_2  ${arg1}  ${arg2}  ${arg3}
...               ${return_data}=   keyword_3
...               keyword_4  {arg11}
```

python would look like this

```
def keyword_rp_once(self, variable, *argv):
    #parse arguments and use robot built in to run each keyword
```

Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, robot doesn't see three lines, it sees one long list of arguments by the time it actually has to run the keyword. When `keyword_rp_once` is called, what the keyword sees is exactly the same as if you had typed this:

```
keyword_rp_once  {variable}  keyword2  ${arg1}  ${arg2}  ${arg3}  ${return_data}=  keyword_3  keyword_4  {arg11}
```

In short, it's impossible for you to do what you want directly in a keyword because robot throws away critical information - the newlines -- so it's impossible for your custom keyword to know where one group of arguments ends and the second group begins.

Note that with the new parser in 3.2, line breaks are available internally, but you would have to do a lot of work to get the information out of the parser and into your keyword via a listener and/or pre-run modifier.

The much simpler choice is to do exactly what robot's own `Run Keywords` does: it forces you to add a marker to tell it where one keyword ends and the next begins (specifically in that keyword, the special argument `AND`). Then, your keyword can split the single long list of arguments into multiple lists of arguments by looking for that marker.

For example, I once did what you're trying to do by using `:` to separate one set of arguments from another. It looked like this:

```
keyword_rp_once  {variable}
...  :  keyword2  ${arg1}  ${arg2}  ${arg3}
...  :  ${return_data}=  keyword_3
...  :  keyword_4  {arg11}
```

It's marginally easier to read, but at the expense of having to write a complicated keyword, and people who know robot but don't know much about your keyword will find the syntax confusing.

This solution will require a surprisingly large amount of work, especially since you have a variable assignment in the middle. Your keyword would have to have a bunch of code to iterate through the arguments, and then add special handling for any argument that looked like `:` or matched a regular expression like `${.*?|=?` or something like that.

Comment: my issue is how do I handle ${return_data}= ? I cant use start_keyword listener due to 3.2.1 version of robot framework.

Comment: I don't know how you can handle it. It may be impossible, robot simply wasn't designed to work this way.

Comment: I think you'll have to call `register_run_keyword`, a method in the BuiltIn library. It's only very briefly mentioned in the user guide. I think calling that will prevent robot from doing variable replacement before calling the root keyword.

Comment: ok I just wanted to totally confirm that this really impossible before I try another tool. If anything changes Ill post the solution here.

Comment: @PatrickCaldwell: I'm not sure I would call it "impossible", but it's definitely difficult and requires a lot of work to get right. It's not something that robot supports out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it by putting the keywords variables between quotes. For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    I execute "ls"
    Sleep for "2" seconds
    I print "ls" with "lah" with file "File"

*** Keywords ***
I execute "${cmd}"
    log to console    ${cmd}

I print "${cmd}" with "${opts}" with file "${input}"
    LOG TO CONSOLE    ${cmd}
    Sleep for "1" seconds
    LOG TO CONSOLE     ${opts}
    Sleep for "10" seconds
    LOG TO CONSOLE     ${input}

Sleep for "${input1}" seconds
    sleep    ${input1}
```

In your case it would be as follows:

```
keyword_rp "{variable}" keyword_2 "${arg1}" "${arg2}" "${arg3}"
```

You can check this page:  https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedding-arguments-into-keyword-name